# Basic example for sharing text or image with UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I started my search by wanting to know how I could share to other apps in iOS. I discovered that two important ways are

- `UIActivityViewController`
- `UIDocumentInteractionController`

These and other methods are compared in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042701/3681880).

Often when I am learning a new concept I like to see a basic example to get me started. Once I get something basic set up I can modify it how I like later.

There are many SO questions related to `UIActivityViewController`, but I couldn't find any that were just asking for a simple example. Since I just learned how to do this, I will provide my own answer below. Feel free to add a better one (or an Objective-C version).

Answer (score 347, accepted):

### UIActivityViewController Example Project

Set up your storyboard with two buttons and hook them up to your view controller (see code below).

[image]

Add an image to your Assets.xcassets. I called mine "lion".

[image]

### Code

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // share text
    @IBAction func shareTextButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        // text to share
        let text = "This is some text that I want to share."
        
        // set up activity view controller
        let textToShare = [ text ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
        
        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook ]
        
        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    // share image
    @IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        // image to share
        let image = UIImage(named: "Image")
        
        // set up activity view controller
        let imageToShare = [ image! ]
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
        
        // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook ]
        
        // present the view controller
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}
```

### Result

Clicking "Share some text" gives result on the left and clicking "Share an image" gives the result on the right.

[image]

### Notes

- I retested this with iOS 11 and Swift 4. I had to run it a couple times in the simulator before it worked because it was timing out. This may be because my computer is slow.
- If you wish to hide some of these choices, you can do that with `excludedActivityTypes` as shown in the code above.
- Not including the `popoverPresentationController?.sourceView` line will cause your app to crash when run on an iPad.
- This does not allow you to share text or images to other apps. You probably want `UIDocumentInteractionController` for that.

### See also

- [Add sharing to your Swift app via UIActivityViewController](http://www.codingexplorer.com/sharing-swift-app-uiactivityviewcontroller/)
- [UIActivity​View​Controller](http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/) from NSHipster
- [`UIActivityViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/)
- [Share extension documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html)
- [comparison with `UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21235934)

Comment: Why some examples show array of 1 item, and some shows 2? Assuming sharing an image.

Comment: @ Suragch: Hi I want to share a referall code in the text and need that code to be copied on click or tap as it happens when we send a number.

Answer (score 117):

**Share :** Text

```
@IBAction func shareOnlyText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = "This is the text....."
    let textShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

**Share :** Image

```
@IBAction func shareOnlyImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let image = UIImage(named: "Product")
    let imageShare = [ image! ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

**Share :** Text - Image - URL

```
   @IBAction func shareAll(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let text = "This is the text...."
    let image = UIImage(named: "Product")
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"https://stackoverflow.com/users/4600136/mr-javed-multani?tab=profile")
    let shareAll= [text , image! , myWebsite]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareAll, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view 
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

[image]

Comment: hey its not working. In FB only link is share not image and text.

Comment: @ScriptKitty. Is messages app configured properly with an i cloud account?

Comment: @EktaPadaliya. According to FB update policy, either a URL or an image can be shared. text can't

Comment: https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift-8de22562a850

Comment: @Mr.JavedMultani image is not shared in whatsapp

Comment: Hi i want to audio and text if a select both in array then only text shows to share and how to add your app logo as audio file default logo in share intent

Comment: Hi @Mr.JavedMultani, is not working for me. I'm sharing 3 items (`text`, `image`, `file`) is not working for me.

Comment: @Harsha above example is for Text - Image - URL, if you want to share file then you need to mention path from document directory/local and can pass it.

Comment: yes, file sharing is working but text is not getting shared along with the file. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72596837/sharing-an-ics-file-along-with-some-text-is-not-working

Answer (score 17):

Just as a note you can also use this for iPads:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
```

So the popover pops from the sender (the button in that case).

Comment: activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender as? UIView      -worked for me. :) thanks

Comment: The Share box wasn't coming up for iPads. This fixed the iPad issues I was having!

Answer (score 13):

I found this to work flawlessly if you want to share whole screen.

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 0.0)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [img!], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I've used the implementation above and just now I came to know that it doesn't work on iPad running iOS 13.
I had to add these lines before present() call in order to make it work

```
//avoiding to crash on iPad
if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
     popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
     popoverController.sourceView = self.view
     popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
}
```

That's how it works for me

```
func shareData(_ dataToShare: [Any]){

        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: dataToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        //exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
        //activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
            //UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook
        //]

        //avoiding to crash on iPad
        if let popoverController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)
        }

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use the following functions which I wrote in one of my helper class in a project.

just call

```
showShareActivity(msg:"message", image: nil, url: nil, sourceRect: nil)
```

and it will work for both iPhone and iPad. If you pass any view's CGRect value by sourceRect it will also shows a little arrow in iPad.

```
func topViewController()-> UIViewController{
    var topViewController:UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!

    while ((topViewController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topViewController = topViewController.presentedViewController!;
    }

    return topViewController
}

func showShareActivity(msg:String?, image:UIImage?, url:String?, sourceRect:CGRect?){
    var objectsToShare = [AnyObject]()

    if let url = url {
        objectsToShare = [url as AnyObject]
    }

    if let image = image {
        objectsToShare = [image as AnyObject]
    }

    if let msg = msg {
        objectsToShare = [msg as AnyObject]
    }

    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = topViewController().view
    if let sourceRect = sourceRect {
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceRect
    }

    topViewController().present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Instead of the series of `if` statements, you can write `[url, image, msg].compactMap({ $0 })`.

Comment: this solution won't work for sharing via whatapp when you try to send both image and message together

Answer (score 3):

**iOS Share text or image**

present `UIActivityViewController`

```
let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [someObject], applicationActivities: nil) 
//someObject can be UIImage, NSURL, String... iOS decide how to handle it properly

controller.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

//add completionWithItemsHandler
controller.completionWithItemsHandler = {
    (
        activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?,
        completed: Bool,
        arrayReturnedItems: [Any]?,
        error: Error?
    ) in
    
    if let error = error {
        //error occured
        return
    }
    
    if completed {
        if let activityType = activityType {
            switch activityType {
            case .saveToCameraRoll:
                break
            case .copyToPasteboard:
                break
            case .addToReadingList:
                break
            case .airDrop:
                break
            default:
                //all others
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Cancel
    }
}

self.present(controller, animated: true)
```

**Save image into library**

If you are going to save image into library add `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` into app's `.plist` file or you get runtime error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

additionally you can exclude this opportunity:

```
controller.excludedActivityTypes = [.saveToCameraRoll]
```

variant with `completionWithItemsHandler` which can helps to add post logic or handle errors.

For example I run into next error when saving UIImage into Photo library in a corresponding handler:

> Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-1 "Unknown error" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown error, NSUnderlyingError=0x600003f85110 {Error Domain=PHPhotosErrorDomain Code=3303 "(null)"}}

As figured out I tried to save `CIImage`. As a variant you can convert it to `CGImage`

```
let context = CIContext()
guard let cgImage = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) else { return nil }
return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

**Customize UIActivityViewController**

```
class ImageActivityItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {
    let image: UIImage
    let title: String
    
    public init(image: UIImage, title: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
    }
    
    func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
        return self.image
    }
    
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
        return self.image
    }
    
    public func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
        let image = self.image
        let imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: image)
        let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
        metadata.title = self.title
        metadata.imageProvider = imageProvider
        return metadata
    }
}
```

using:

```
let imageActivityItemSource = ImageActivityItemSource(image: image, title: "Share this image with others")
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageActivityItemSource], applicationActivities: nil)
```