# Sharing to social media that install on phone iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is there any specific method to share button that detect all social media apps on your iOS phone ?

example : my phone have whatsapp and twitter installed. so when I pressed share button only whatsapp and twitter came out, not facebook and any other apps not installed on my phone.

In android there's particular intent to use that kind of method. However in iOS I still can't find it.

Note : I need it for Swift 3 programmatically

Any help is very useful, Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at `UIActivityViewController`?

Comment: Let me search for it thanks @rmaddy

Comment: Thanks man for the information, It's done now @rmaddy

Comment: See my answer provided on this stackoverflow link: [How to implement “share button” in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938722/how-to-implement-share-button-in-swift/54136054#54136054)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try this:

```
@IBAction func shareImageButton(_ sender: UIButton) 
{

    // image to share
    let image = UIImage(named: "Image")

    // set up activity view controller
    let imageToShare = [ image! ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: imageToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash

    // exclude some activity types from the list (optional)
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.postToFacebook ]

    // present the view controller
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I've done my research and it works. Thanks anyways. Cheers!