# Run app target from inside the same app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, target, ios-extensions

Is it possible to execute an app target from inside the app. For example, I want to open the Share extension for the same application directly when I press a button. Is this possible?

Comment: This may help you [$How to implement share button in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938722/how-to-implement-share-button-in-swift).

Comment: May be my question wasn't clear enough, I want to open the share extension for my app directly without showing the share sheet.