# UIActivityController not showing from bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, uimenucontroller

I am using TextView which has a default property copy, lookup, share etc. when i click on share ativityController appears but it's not appearing from bottom, can we change the frame position?

**Here is the image of what I am getting,**

[image]

Comment: You can check this link maybe it can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35931947/4935811

Comment: could you share your code .. what you did ?

Comment: i haven't use a code for that, have a TextView which has editable off , when user highlight a text  UIMenuController will show with copy , look up and share menu , when user click on share  the above send view will appear everything is fine except that position @NazmulHasan

Comment: @SourLeangChhean i am not asking how to show share , i am using simply textView to show default share nothing more but why the frame is not in a correct frame ?