# Is this native to iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find what this share popup would be called or if it is even a native iOS object. So I'm asking what would this popup be called if I can find it in apple's documentation.  And if I can't, how can I recreate it?

[image: share popup]

Comment: FYI - In the future, if you wish to know about what controls/views are available, consult the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/). It covers all of this stuff.

Comment: Great thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is native iOS Popup and called UIActivityViewController, for more details you can refer to below links...

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller 
http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/

Answer (score 2):

You're after the `UIActivityViewController`.

[Here is a link to the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller)

Answer (score 0):

This "popup" is indeed natively integrated into iOS. It's called `UIActivityViewController`.
Here's code to create one:

```
let stuffToBeShared = [""]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: stuffToBeShared, applicationActivities: nil)
activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35931947/3397217) for more detailed information.