# How apple implement `UIActivityViewController`?

Tags: ios, swift

Just for curiosity， how apple implement `UIActivityViewController`, as the `UIModalPresentationStyle` of `UIActivityViewController` is `popover`, and in the doc, it says `In a horizontally compact environment, this option behaves the same as fullScreen.`, but obviously, the `UIActivityViewController` is not in full screen.
How can apple implement this, does apple use some private behaviors for this ?

I know How to use `UIActivityViewController`, my question is how apple implement `UIActivityViewController`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you mean you need to show activityIndicator in full screen.?

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore no, it's UIActivityViewController, not activityIndicator, I don't understand how to implement this.

Comment: @Nitish it is not duplicate question. You should read it before flag

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Could you kindly help me come closer to the requirement then ?

Comment: @Nitish **Just for curiosity， how apple implement UIActivityViewController** And check your flagged answer

Comment: @Nitish My question is not about how to use UIActivityViewController, it's about how apple implement UIActivityViewController, how I can create a custom view controller like UIActivityViewController.

Comment: For me it doesn't seems that he is asking how to share text or image with ActivityViewcontroller does he ? @Nitish

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Sorry I didn't get that. **And check your flagged answer**. Which answer ?

Comment: @Nitish I mean to say https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931946/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift is not answer of this question both are different

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Then please clearly tag the link instead of just posting it as unclear text.

Comment: @JIEWANG : My apologies then. Will retract my close vote.

Comment: @JIEWANG It is simple to implement like this. You can create view controller with same controls with transparent background and present it with custom animation

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya yes, it's easy to do if we use custom, but what UIActivityViewController do is it's use `popover` as UIModalPresentationStyle.

Comment: @JIEWANG There are many sample on github for how to make something like this. For example, you can check https://github.com/fergusding/iOS-Custom-ActionSheet. It's about custom action sheet but it shows you how to create something like `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: @JIEWANG A `blackOverlayView` + `aView`. `aView` is a main white `actionSheet` and you can use `UICollectionView` to showing the options and it can horizontally scroll as well.