# Share using Message in ActivityViewController swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app which can share a text using activity view controller but when I press message option in share sheet nothing happens how to share a text using message in share sheet.

Comment: This will help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931946/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift

Comment: Can you share some of your implementation please?

Comment: [MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText] returns NO. iam getting this message. sms will not work in simulator??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot test that on iOS Simulator. This is one of the limitations. You also cannot test push notifications, iCloud, etc.
You need to join Apple's iOS Developer Program and test the app on your device.