# How to open twitter using url to post an image on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, ios-universal-links, deeplink

I was able to find the url to share plain text (twitter://post?message=Hi there!).
But I need to post an image along with text.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Basic example for sharing text or image with UIActivityViewController in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931946/basic-example-for-sharing-text-or-image-with-uiactivityviewcontroller-in-swift)

Comment: The deep links for Twitter’s apps are not documented or supported.

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Actually, I want to skip UIActivityViewController and directly share the content. Adding this to the question details.

Comment: @AndyPiper seems like so, couldn't find anything :(